# Select line after finding keyword

Tags: vb.net

I wanted to make a piece of code that selects the line in a text file when it finds the keyword that it's searching for. I have no clue what to actually do, what I searched up didn't help, was outdated, or for another language. I would need this code for vb.net. Thank you.

An example of what I mean.

Let's say we wanna search for: SO11

And there's other lines.

(1) : HJ6
(2) : 46J
(3) : SO11
(4) : NTE
(5) : 4UJ

And the searched line is in line 3. I want it to select line 3 and have it dimmed into a string so I can use it for future things.

Comment: How do you "select" a line in a text file?  Do you have it displayed in some kind of control?

Comment: `I have no clue what to actually do, what I searched up didn't help, was outdated, or for another language. I would need this code for vb.net.`. Please show us an attempt so we can help you, we help with specific problems and currently you do not have any.

Answer (score 0):

Try breaking you question up into smaller chunks.  You might be thinking to broadly.
For example:

1. Read Text File
2. While reading text file If file contains SO11 then save that line to variable.(Looping through that file.)
3. Do stuff with that variable.

Give that a try and let us know how it goes.